# when i run my app nothing is showing(text fields,buttons...) except the Gradient background, I'm working on the interface for now

Tags: swift, user-interface

```
import UIKit

class MainVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        }
    func backgroundcolor(){
        let newLayer = CAGradientLayer()
                    newLayer.colors = [UIColor.init(red: 0.2705882353, green: 0.4823529412, blue: 0.6156862745, alpha: 1).cgColor,UIColor.init(red: 0.6588235294, green: 0.8549019608, blue: 0.862745098, alpha: 1).cgColor]
                    newLayer.frame = view.frame
                    view.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the problem that you face?

Comment: Did you add buttons and textfield through storyboard?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have on my user interface couple of buttons and text fileds, but when I run the app they don't show, the only thing that shows is the gradient color.

Comment: from where you are calling `backgroundcolor()` function? please share the whole code.

Answer (score 2):

In your `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, call your function. Any changes related to layout should be done in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
import UIKit

class MainVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        }
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        backgroundColor()
        }
    func backgroundcolor(){
        let newLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        newLayer.colors = [UIColor.init(red: 0.2705882353, green: 0.4823529412, blue: 0.6156862745, alpha: 1).cgColor,UIColor.init(red: 0.6588235294, green: 0.8549019608, blue: 0.862745098, alpha: 1).cgColor]
        newLayer.frame = view.frame
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(newLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
let gradientView = UIView()
gradientView.frame = view.bounds

let newLayer = CAGradientLayer()
newLayer.colors = [UIColor.init(red: 0.2705882353, green: 0.4823529412, blue: 0.6156862745, alpha: 1).cgColor,UIColor.init(red: 0.6588235294, green: 0.8549019608, blue: 0.862745098, alpha: 1).cgColor]
newLayer.frame = gradientView.bounds
gradientView.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)

self.view.addSubview(gradientView)
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(gradientView)
```